# In EF Core, querying with FromSqlInterpolated() method on an entity that has an OwnedEntity doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, owned-types

I have some complex entities in my context.

```
DbSet<EntityA> AEntities { get; set; }
DbSet<EntityB> BEntities { get; set; }
```

where `EntityA` inherits `EntityB` (it's a superset of it).  There is a column `Discriminator` that was created by Entity Framework to distinguish between the 2.  Up to here, no problem.

EntityA also has an Owned Type:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().OwnsOne(p => p.OwnedThing,
                ot =>
                {
                    // ot......;
                    ot.ToTable("SectionTrailInfo");
                });
```

As long as I use only EF to query the database, it's still all right.

But then for performance reasons I need to query an BEntities with a SQL Stored Proc.

```
// ...
return await BEntities.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC GetManyRecords @Id = {id}").ToListAsync();
```

That also worked before introducing the Owned Entity in EntityA.  Now I get a `'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.` error.  The error is thrown as soon as I try the .ToQueryString() method.

I have tried modifying the Stored Proc to Left Join the Owned Type but it doesn't change a thing.  In fact the query is never formed and never sent to the DB server.  So I have to tell EF Core in a way or another how to deal with the Owned Type (that is not even part of this Entity, but a related one).

My only other option is to re-design completely my schema to removed the Owned Type but I am hoping I can avoid that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the target EF Core version?

Comment: @IvanStoev v5.0.5

Comment: Then convert SP to TVF. This way it would be composable. Then you can even [map it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-queryable-function-to-a-table-valued-function) or just use it as shown. The key is that SqlServer SPs are not composable (`select * from (your_sql_query)` is not valid.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah!  Thanks.  That worked.  Can I mark your comment as the answer?  And... what a weird behavior?  I don't understand the "why".  But at least I can move on :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Here is the explanation in EF Core official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kindly pointed out by @IvanStoev, the way to go is to use a Table-Valued-Function instead of a Stored Proc, in SQL.